# Drupal 8: Twig Grouping Template

Tags: drupal, twig

How to overwrite views-view-grouping.html.twig template, when I habe view called "My view" and I am grouping rows with taxonomy term "Format"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Template file should be named as `views-view-grouping--[view machine name]--[view block id].html.twig`.
Enable twig debug in drupal 8 to get more helps regarding templates.

Comment: Oke I actually manage to integrate that. My problem was that grouping template works only after second group. I would also like to approach individual fields. Is there a way to do that from grouping template?

Comment: @Armin, share screenshot of view i'm unable to understand the issue. you have integrated grouping for 2 fields and want to group all fields. is it so ?